# Bitbucket's pipelines don't recognize the installed python libraries

Tags: python, bitbucket, python-sphinx, bitbucket-pipelines

**Objective:** I am trying to generate sphinx documentation in a bitbucket pipeline.

**Problem:** While everything about the pipeline works, sphinx seems to have issues with finding some modules:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module ... from module ...;
the following exception was raised: No module named 'pandas'
```

As the message says, it is because it could not find `pandas`.

This usually happens when a library that is called in the project is needed by sphinx but it is not installed. For this reason, I install all modules listed in my `requirements.txt`, including `pandas` of course. However, I still get the same warning.

**Consequence:** These warnings makes the generated html files empty (only the modules names may appear there).

---

**More on pipes:** My pipeline has 3 steps:

1. Install python moduels: `pip install -r requirements.txt`, (successfully done)
2. Generate sphinx documentations, (successfully done, with warnings as mentioned above)
3. rsync the results to a remote server, (irrelevant to the issue)

Here you can see my pipeline configuration: [bitbucket-pipelines.yml](https://bitbucket.org/gsudmlab/mvtsdata_toolkit/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml)

---

**Troubleshooting 1**: I have executed this very project, on my machine, with the exact same configurations, and I get no warning about missing modules. If I use another virtualenv in which `pandas` (for example) is missing, then sphinx will start complaining about it, as I showed above.

**Troubleshooting 2**: A typical response to this kind of problem is to check `sys.path` in `conf.py`. Not finding a module (in my case) has nothing to do with how I added `sys.path` in `conf.py`. If that was the case, sphinx would have had problems with **all** modules.

Comment: Are you running this on a Mac? Make sure to install the requirements.txt on the same version the pipeline is using.

Comment: @Jortega no, I run it locally on Ubuntu 18. The bitbucket's pipeline is also using the same `requirements.txt` that I tested locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every pipeline steps runs in a separate docker container, that is why your dependencies are missing in the second step. You need to run sphinx in the same step where you also install your dependencies, for example:

```
image: python:3.6.8

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
        - step:
            name: doc generator
            trigger: manual
            caches:
              - pip
            script:
              - apt-get update && apt-get -y install python-sphinx

              # INSTALL YOUR DEPENDENCIES HERE
              - pip install -r requirements.txt  

              - pip install sphinx_rtd_theme
              - cd sphinxdocs
              - make clean
              - sphinx-apidoc -o . ..
              - make html
            artifacts:
              - sphinxdocs/_build/html/**
```

Comment: Seems to be the case. Thanks.